# The dependency graph in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, plot, graph, ode

I've got the following function:

```
phi0 = [0; 0];   %initial values
[T,PHI] = ode45(@eqn,[0, 10], phi0,odeset('RelTol',2e-13,'AbsTol',1e-100));
plot(T, PHI(:,1),'-b',T, PHI(:,2),'-g');
title('\it  d = 0.1')
w1 = PHI(end,1)/(10000*2*pi)  %the limit frequency for phi1
w2 = PHI(end,2)/(10000*2*pi)  %the limit frequency for phi2
delta_w = w2 - w1
phi1_at_t_10k = PHI(end,1)    %the value phi1(t=10000)
phi2_at_t_10k = PHI(end,2)
```

```
function dy_dt = eqn(t,phi)
  d = 0.1; %synchronization parameter
  n = 3;   
  g = [ 1.01; 1.02];
  f = g-sin(phi/n);
  exch = [d;-d]*sin(phi(2)-phi(1));
  dy_dt = f+exch;
end
```

The `w` is calculated by the formula: `w_i = (1/2pi)(lim((phi(t)-phi(0))/t)` where `t->infinity` (here it's equal to `10000`).
[image: better view]

The question is how to plot the dependence of `delta_w` on different values of `d` (from d=0 to d=5 with step = 0.1)?

Comment: There exists `arrayfun` to convert one array into another by applying a user-supplied function to each element. You would have to put your code from assigning `d` to the computation of `d` into a function. Pass `d` as Args via odeset option or via anonymous function `@(t,y) eqn(t,y,d)`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you! so should I make an array of `d` via `arrayfun` and then could you also tell me how to plot its dependency on `delta_w`?

Comment: @LutzLehmann or I didn't understand it properly?

Comment: obviously, somewhere you start with `function delta_w = f(d)`. Let's make a mock-up, `f = @(d) d*d;` then you can compute `d = [0:0.1:5]; delta_w = arrayfun(f,d); plot(d,delta_w);`

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry but probably I'm doing something wrong cause all I get is quadratic dependence of `d` from `d*d`. Could you please tell me how to do it  in more detail? Thank you!

Comment: You have to actually put the integration code into `f`, it was a very simplified example, a mock-up.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so I need to make a `fuinction delta_w = f(d)`, put `[T, Y] = ode45(...)` there and write the rest code out of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect summarize my comments:

First make the parameter `d` explicit in the ODE function

```
function dy_dt = eqn(t,phi,d)
  n = 3;   
  g = [ 1.01; 1.02];
  f = g-sin(phi/n);
  exch = [d;-d]*sin(phi(2)-phi(1));
  dy_dt = f+exch;
end
```

Then put the ODE integration and evaluation of the result in its own procedure

```
function delta_w = f(d)
  phi0 = [0; 0];   %initial values
  opts = odeset('RelTol',2e-13,'AbsTol',1e-100);
  [T,PHI] = ode45(@(t,y)eqn(t,y,d), [0, 10], phi0, opts);
  w1 = PHI(end,1)/(10000*2*pi);  %the limit frequency for phi1
  w2 = PHI(end,2)/(10000*2*pi);  %the limit frequency for phi2
  delta_w = w2 - w1;
end
```

And finally evaluate for the list of `d` values under consideration

```
d = [0:0.1:5];
delta_w = arrayfun(@(x)f(x),d);
plot(d,delta_w);
```

This should give a result. If it is not the expected one, further research into assumptions, equations and code is necessary.

Comment: I've tried to do it the same way but I've got an error 'Unrecognized func or variable `d`'  at string `delta-w = arrayfun(f,d);` and some errors with odearguments and ode45 (`[T,PHI] = ode45(@(t,y)eqn(t,y,d), [0, 10], phi0, opts);`)

Comment: This is a problem with passing functions (in octave?), one needs an anonymous function as correct function reference. Changed above, gets an arc that resembles `1/x` that falls from 8e-7 to 1.5e-8

Comment: thank you a lot! You've really helped me!